# The Envelope Theorem, Some Workings/Substitution

Tags: mathematical-economics

I have an application of the envelope theorem below, and would love some feedback on the steps taken to get from (2) - (3) and (3) - (4) and (4) - (5)

The overall question is: 'derive the marginal value for human capital in the second year' using the second-period value function, with parameters:

- human capital $k_2$
- savings $m_2$
- consumption good price $p_2$
- labour wage $w_2$
- labour supply $l_2$

The value function is given:

**(1)**              $$V(k_2,m_2;p_2,w_2) = max_{c_2,l_2} u(c_2, l_2)$$
s.t $$ p_2c_2 = w_2k_2l_2+m_2$$

**(2)** With the budget constraint substituted into the objective we get:

$$V(k_2,m_2;p_2,w_2)=u(w_2,kl_2(k_2,m_2;p_2,w_2+m)/p_2,l_2(k_2,m_2;p_2,w_2)$$

**(3)** By the envelope theorem

$$\frac{dV(k_2;m_2;p_2,w_2)}{dk}= [\frac{d}{dk}u ((w_2kl_2+m_2)/p_2,l_2]_{l_2=l_2(k_2,m_2;p_2,w_2)}$$

**(4)** $$= [u_c((w_2kl_2+m_2/p_2,l_2)\frac{w_2l_2}{p_2}]_{l_2=l_2=(k_2,m_2;p_2,w_2)}$$

**(5)** $$=u_c(k_2,m_2;p_2,w_2),l_2(k_2,m_2;p_2,w_2))\frac {w_2l_2(k_2,m_2;p_2,w_2)}{p_2}$$

**Screenshot uploaded for clarity**

[image]

Comment: Is it not something like $\partial V/\partial k = \lambda w l$ where $\lambda = \partial V/\partial m$?

Comment: Hi Jesper, thanks for your contribution. I've uploaded a screenshot for clarity

Comment: Which is the same because $\lambda = \partial V/\partial m = \frac{\partial u/\partial c} {p}$. I think (fast look could make mistake.. so you should chek)

Comment: You can measure the value of relaxing the constraint either in terms of getting more $m$ or in terms of getting $\partial u/\partial c$ more utility per dollar/euro therefore divided by $p$ the price of $c$

Comment: Ok - that makes sense in terms of what you've said. Thank you.